# Create a unreadable PHP page for capthca

Tags: php, javascript, security, .htaccess, captcha

I'm using the cool-captcha for my registration form. 
This is the Captcha generated picture code which I'm using inside my codes:

```
<img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" />
```

Anyone can directly go to "captcha.php" page and view the image. So my question is, is there anyway to disable the direct access or direct viewing of Captcha.php in browser ? I just want the Captcha.php can only be used to view inside the img source not in direct viewing by browsers. Is there anyway to do in php or htaccess file ?

Thanks

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715447/disable-access-to-included-files

Comment: But what would be wrong with someone requesting your Captcha directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course use `.htaccess` in the same manner as in preventing hotlinking of images

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^hellothere/captcha\.php$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: I don't see the result ? by the way, I'm using localhost on MAMP : http://localhost:8888/hellothere/captcha.php

Comment: Which result? What don't you see?

Comment: I mean I can still access to captcha.php directly on my browser.

Comment: Did you use the full path to the `captcha.php` file or just copied the above code? If so, see the updated last line of it.

Comment: I used this for 3rd line " RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?localhost:8888/hellothere/ [NC] " , and 4th line" RewriteRule ^path/to/captcha\.php$ - [NC,F,L] " in htaccess

Comment: If your `DocumentRoot` is under `http://localhost:8888` then your last line should be `RewriteRule ^hellothere/captcha\.php$ - [NC,F,L]`

Answer (score 1):

There is no effective way to block this, because there are solutions to even render an URL in image. In this case, even if you spent your effort to block the captcha, with rendered image of URL (saving the buffer xvfb on Linux for example) would be sufficient to get captcha cutting this image with X, Y coordinates. By the way... Another solutions like validate  referer or ajax requests can be bypassed with tools like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hackbar/

Comment: can you explain more a bit ? I mean in a way of coding ? thanks

Comment: Yes, try this site http://www.converturl.net/ in resume to extract an captcha you need only a render html component - In Delphi you can use THttpBrowser, in C++ (Qt) you can use QtWebKit, or just open Firefox by comand line in console and get a print screen. With this printscreen you can crop captcha using X, Y coordinates. As you can see it's a useless effort try block captcha to be extracted

Answer (score 0):

To stop direct access to any PHP script, **add this line at the top of the script**

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

To allow AJAX requests:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH') &&
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
exit('No direct acess allowed...');
```

Comment: I just tried this, but I can't see the image captcha anymore in my form !

Comment: IMO - you are not using any AJAX request for captcha.php, so just  use if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Comment: Are you adding this line to captcha.php or your script ? ** Add this line to captcha.php **

Comment: can you show me how you are generating an object of captcha class ?

Comment: I saw the cool-captcha class. I want to see how you are creating an object of that class and using ite.g $myCaptcha = new SimpleCaptcha(); $mycaptcha->createImage(); .................

Comment: I did't touch anything on cool-captcha class. everything is default. I just added " <img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" /> " to my html form.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the answer is NO; at least not in any secure way. For the server there is hardly any difference between a browser calling the page because it's the `src` of your `<img>` tag, or just someone typing the url into the browser.

I'm also not sure what kind of problem you're trying to avoid. What is the problem with someone seeing your captcha without the page around it (if they really wanted to...).

Some idea's to make it harder to see it not-in-the-form:

- Check for HTTP_REFERER. Note that some virus scanners and internet security packages kill the HTTP_REFERER header as well, so these people won't be able to see your captcha ever.
- Check for some URL parameter at the top op captcha.php (for instance only allow access when it's captcha.php?secret=123456789). In your form.php page you know the secret, other people won't (in theory). You can make the secret change over time: (`$secret = md5($salt . strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"));`), and then check in captcha.php whether the secret is either this minute or last minute's secret (`$now = time(); $_REQUEST["secret"] == strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M", $now) || $_REQUEST["secret"] == strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M", $now - 60)`)
- generate a new random secret on each request of form.php, and check that in captcha.php (you will need memcached (or similar) to store the secret once it's generated, and then remove it once it's used).
- when executing form.php, set `$SESSION["captcha_ok"] = 1;`, and in captcha.php do `if (!$SESSION["captcha_ok"]) {show_error();} else {$SESSION["captcha_ok"]=0; etc....`

But once again, none of these method will actually really prevent those people who really want to, to view your captcha without the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$no=rand(0,567890);
$_SESSION['imgno']=$no;
?>
<img src="load.php?sc=<?php echo $no; ?>" width="300px" height="300px" />
</body>
</html>
```

**load.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
if(isset($_SESSION['imgno']))
{


    readfile("student1.jpg");
    unset($_SESSION['imgno']);
}
else
{
    readfile("thumbs.gif");
}


?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Please reformat your code sample(s). It is not just an inconvinience to potential readers, its actually naive to make the assumption that someone will bother. Formatting code matters, and posting badly formatted code sends a signal that the poster is lazy and expects others to do it for them.